# Magento oAuth issue with varnish

Tags: rest, magento, oauth, magento-1.9

I *think* i have an issue with my config of varnish in relation to my oAuth setup. I've got all of the consumer tokens etc set up in accordance with the docs, but if i try to hit the end points associated with the oAuth/API end points they all return 404s.

I've tested everything else I can, and have narrowed it down to this. Does anyone have any experience with this issue?

Comment: Can you share your varnish config and oauth endpoints in the backend? Its possible that there's something wrong with your varnish config.

Comment: we just used the default config that gets applied by varnish when you install it - varnish is actually managed by Turpentine (it's a magento varnish cache controller plugin)

Comment: I'm not sure if you know how varnish works. It sits in front of your web server (apache/nginx etc) and receives all http requests. Based on the http request and your varnish config (vcl), it either does (A) a cache lookup and returns response without touching the backend (magento) or (B) makes a request to backend, adds/does not add to cache and returns the response. What appears in your case is that its not able to connect to the backend. You might want to run varnishlog to debug. FYI since varnish runs only in memory, there is no file logging by default, as in apache.